# Java run JarInputStream

Tags: java, jar, encryption

I have searched for hours and not found anything about this.

I have a jarinputstream who reads a crypted jar and decrypts it

```
JarInputStream jin = new JarInputStream(new CipherInputStream(in, dcipher));
```

I got that confirmed working because it prints out class names when I do

```
while ((je = jin.getNextJarEntry()) != null) {
      jename = je.getName();
```

If I print out jename, it will print out the class name and path so I know it decrypts well.

But now, when I wanna run Main.class, I have NO clue about how doing this. I do not wanna save the file to disk, just keep this in memory.

Any tip about how I can create and run a jar in memory from that jarinputstream?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to subclass `ClassLoader` and implement `findClass()` to get the decrypted data for a given class and send it to `super.defineClass()`.

See the [ClassLoader](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/ClassLoader.html) docs, or you can get some inspiration from [the JarClassLoader tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/jarclassloader.html), or possibly http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/javaqa/2003-05/01-qa-0509-jcrypt.html?page=2 or [Loading Encrypted JarFile Via URLCassloader](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13965095/loading-encrypted-jarfile-via-urlcassloader)